# Vim: remove matching braces and the first word in the braces

Tags: regex, vim, latex

For example, change

> text 12345 {\color{red}text 123 \ref{label} 567
>
> 1234} 567

to

> text 12345 text 123 \ref{label} 567
>
> 1234 567

What kind of operation should be done in vim?

I aim to find every all patterns `{\color{red}`
and remove the pattern and the matching brace `}` for the pattern,
while keeping the text in between.
The pattern `{\color{red}` can be anywhere in the line (not necessarily at the beginning of the line).
The text between the `{\color{red} ...}` can have multiple lines as shown above.

Thanks a lot for your help.

**Edit**:
I just find a way to do it, but may not be efficient enough.

```
:g/\\color{red}/norm ndiBvaBpd%
```

`g`: global
`/\\color{red}`: match the pattern
`/norm`: normal mode command
`n`: forward the cursor to next matching pattern from the cursor. But if the pattern is at the beginning of the line, it may fail to find it.
`diB`: delete inner block from the cursor
`vaB`: select block around the cursor
`p`: put to the selected block
`d%`: delete `\color{red}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

didn't get what do you really mean. there are many ways could do it.

```
{\color{red}text 123 \ref{label} 567}
^
|cursor
```

you could do: 
<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>}</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>

if you have surround.vim installed, removing surrounding braces would be easier. (`ds{`)

**EDIT**

for the question update:

open your file, and type:

```
:g#{\\color{red}#normal 0df}$x
```

hope the command does what you want.

**EDIT II** based on question update

if your target text object is crossing lines, you could try this:

```
g/{\\color{red}/normal 0f{mz%x`zxdf}
```

above line works if your target pattern crossing multiple lines (not only one/two, could be many). However the syntax must be correct, which means, the `{ , }` **must be paired**.

Comment: Surround is would be highly recommended in this situation.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I mean to find every all patterns: `{\color{red}` and remove the pattern and the matching brace `}` for the pattern, while keeping the text in between. In other words, I want to remove the color of the text in the file.

Comment: @AndyRay you are right, I wrote a stupid command without testing. :) I added a new one. hope this one works

Comment: @Kent Sorry for the unclear description of the question since it's my first question in stackoverflow. I have modified the question. I tried you command. It would delete all text till end of the line, which is not my goal. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a substitution with regex for this:

`%s/\v\{\\color\{\w+\}(.*)} ?$/\1`

`\v` very magic (sane regexes)

`{\\color\{\w+\}` the color thingy

`(.*)` capture the text you want to save

`} ?$` closing nipple bracket and optional space at the end of the line

`/\1` replace the whole thing with the first capture, which is stuff between color tag BS

For your edited example, you can use `\_.` instead of `.` because it includes linebreak characters.

`%s/\v\{\\color\{\w+\}(\_.*)}/\1`

Comment: if i wrote `:s`, I would do the same however 1, keep the `red` instead of `\w+` since he mentioned "red". 2, remove the ending `g`, we don't need that flag. how many `$` can a line has? 3. it is nice to consider the trailing spaces/tabs , then better with `\s*` anyway, nice command. +1

Comment: @AndyRay Thanks. It works if the text is in one line. But if the text lies in multiple lines, it will ignore the following lines. Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: Hi, I tried the new command. It seems not work properly. It will replace the pattern form the first `{\color{red}` to the last `}`. However, I aim to find the pattern with matched `{\color{red}...}`. I tried Kent's way, which works. Thanks a lot for your help.